# Insert data in selected columns

Tags: php, insert, cakephp-1.3

I am using cakephp with php, I have table with field id having data type auto number.

In my form I do not have any field with id that's why it sets blank in my model and when I tries to save data it gives error.

how can I insert data into selected columns using model in cakephp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pull the form data, make sure you are using an array with the model name and field names. For example, if you are saving a book to the book model, the array would look something like:

```
$data['Book']['name'] = 'Title of Book';
$data['Book']['author'] = 'Name of Author';
$data['Book']['pages'] = 205; // number of pages
```

Then when you save the data, you must call create, then save:

```
$this->Book->create();
$this->Book->save($data);
```

This will automatically add the ID (whether auto-increment or UUID) and save the new record.